# Windows 7 and LDAP

Tags: windows, ldap

Does Windows 7 make use of the Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) at all?  If so, where and how?  Do I have to install anything special for this?  Is there a difference amongst the editions of Windows 7 (Home, Ultimate, &c.) with respect to LDAP?

Is it directly accessible to me, an end user?  Are tools provided by Microsoft for making LDAP lookups?  If so, what are they?  If not, are there third-party tools for using LDAP on Windows 7?

What about running an LDAP server on Windows 7?

Comment: -1, question does not show research effort. If you don't know what it is, you *probably* won't need it ;) LDAP is used for looking up information from a server, typically contact details in huge offices, but also devices and files. What exactly do you need it for? Do you have a small office?

Comment: Yes, I have small office. I installed it on my laptop. But dont know how to use it.

Comment: What did you install on your laptop?

Comment: I installed open LDAP on my laptop. (http://www.userbooster.de/en/download/openldap-for-windows.aspx) , at the moment I dont know how to start. Any ideas?

Comment: @AtaA-Design you are asking wrong questions. Make some effort. Read the Docs. Use Search.

Answer (score 3):

LDAP is: Lightweight Directory Access Protocol

is a hierarchial database suited to be used in the organizations to store the records.

In Windows if your machine is joined to Active Directory domain you already using LDAP.

LDAP is a standard and Active Directory supports it and using it (working through that protocol).

Treat it like a database of data about the personal in your company.

It's not for end users it's rather for administrators. So if you are asking what is it and how can you use it, then, probably, **you don't really need it**.

Comment: I want to use it in small office. I have downloaded LDAP for windows. So, I am the administrator. How can I start using it? It seems it does not have an interface. Can you explain me how should I start? Thanks.

Comment: Just use WIndows Server and create Active Directory domain that would mean that you are using LDAP.

For what purposes you want to use it?

Comment: In our office, there are about 10 people. We have one server computer. All our computers use wireless network. My task is: to research and install LDAP for our office. My supervisor gave me this task. I had no idea about LDAP, I learnt that it is a centralized directory which our informations stored. (computer names, printers, emails, name, surname, etc) That is why I am asking it, what should I do now? I downloaded one LDAP for windows. How can I start? Or is it already installed on server computer? I want a wide idea about LDAP. Thanks, will be grateful for your help.

Comment: You can go easier way. Just install Active Directory and join all your users to the domain. Man, you need to learn a lot :D Active Directory actually a huge huge topic. Don't expect to get all your answer here. To the original question I gave an answer. You can accept it and go further :D

Comment: Man, my supervisor said that I won't use Active Directory, he said that I should build its interface in Java, and so we will be able to connect to LDAP by Java. Any ideas?

Comment: @AtaA-Design Why haven't you said anything about the whole circumstances before? You're facing a lot of different issues, and your supervisor is expecting you to do stuff you don't have the slightest clue about. No personal offense, but this seems to be way over your head. I would suggest you take your time, write a detailed question, and then post it on [SF], where questions about maintaining networks in the professional workplace are on topic.

Comment: Ok brothers, thanks, that is true! I am confused now, sorry!